# infinite scroll with masonry and imagesloaded not working well (tumblr)

Tags: javascript, tumblr, infinite-scroll, masonry, imagesloaded

I made some combination between the old code and the new one but it still doesnt work properly as some posts still overlap. They might not overlap for a smaller resolution tho, so here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F9pE.jpg), and you can see the site [here](http://derovada.tumblr.com).

the sources:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/2.0b2.120519/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.0.4/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
```

and the code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var $container = $('#posts');
$container.masonry(),
$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector : "div.navigation",
// selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : ".navigation a#next",
// selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : ".entry",
// selector for all items you'll retrieve
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 10000,
loadingImg : "http://static.tumblr.com/bcpenwm/o5Nmy3k0o/florels.gif",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
},
// call masonry as a callback.
  function( newElements ) {
            // hide new items while they are loading
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
            // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                // show elems now they're ready
                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
            });}
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the problem lies with tumblr's photoset variable. Tumblr generates an iframe and masonry is unable to grab its height to leave space for it. Instead use something like [Pixel Union's extended photosets](https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset). This loads the photosets as images and masonry is then able to grab their height.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I was having a similar issue with photosets and masonry and chloe's suggestion wasn't working. However, there is another alternative. Tumblr has functionality to replace the photoset variable with actual photos instead and someone has built a plugin to reorganize them into a grid: [Photoset Grid](http://stylehatch.github.io/photoset-grid/).  That webpage provides a handy tutorial on how to implement the code into a tumblr theme as well.